# insert to sql with php

Tags: php, mysql

i know that there are a lot of topics on this side regarding my problem but it seems that i'm missing something when i do it:

the code is below :

```
mysql_select_db("person");
$query = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE email='$_POST[email]' AND cc='$_POST[zip]"; 
$rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>=1){ echo "blablabla"; } else {
$sql="INSERT INTO `email` (`email`, `cc`),
VALUES
(`$_POST[email]`, `$_POST[zip]`)";
mysql_query($sql);
echo "blablabla";
```

this is the error i get on page: 
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1"

thanks

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a lot of error in your query.Try this instead

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."' AND cc='".$_POST['zip']."'"; 
//you need to put quote before the variable name of $_POST
```

And also

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `email` (`email`, `cc`)
VALUES
('".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['zip']."')";
```

don't use backtick on values,backtick is use only to the table or column name that is same as reserved or key word of sql

Answer (score 3):

### Note:

- You're using *backticks (`)* instead of *apostrophe (')* in the variables in your insert query. It is alright to use it in your column name, but not in your variables.
- You should also remove your *comma (,)* in your insert query.
- In your *SELECT query*, you're missing another apostrophe for your `$_POST['zip']` variable.

Your insert query should look like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `email` (`email`, `cc`) VALUES ('$_POST[email]', '$_POST[zip]')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

You should also consider using at least *escape string function* or *prepared statement* to prevent [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Your *prepared statement* insert query should look like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO email (email, cc) VALUES (?,?)"; /* QUERY */
$stmt = $YourDBConnection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['email'], $_POST['zip']); /* BIND VARIABLES TO YOUR QUERY */

$stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
```